# Html.fromHtml shows commented line

Tags: android, html, textview

`Html.fromHtml` successfully renders the text, *however*, the HTML which I have contains a comment:

```
<!-- p {margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0}-->
```

And this comment line is showing in my `TextView`:

[image]

How do I prevent the comment line from showing?

**Code**

```
public String getFormattedBody()
{
    String formattedContent;

    if (contentType.equalsIgnoreCase("html"))
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        {
            formattedContent = Html.fromHtml(content, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY).toString();
        }
        else
        {
            formattedContent = Html.fromHtml(content).toString();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return content;
    }

    return formattedContent;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a regular expression to manually remove the comment:

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<!--(.*?)-->");
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(formattedContent);

while (matcher.find())
{
    final String htmlComment = matcher.group();
    formattedContent = formattedContent.replace(htmlComment, "");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just brutally get rid of them.

```
.replaceAll("(?s)<!--.*?-->", "")
```